# Download attribute on anchor tag has stopped working on cross domain

Tags: javascript, html, download, attributes, anchor

From last couple of days, i find that the download attribute on anchor tag has stopped working on cross domains and instead of downloading content from that cross domain, we are redirected to view that content.

Any workarounds using js would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
var a = document.createElement('a'); 
a.href = selectedStore.pdfLink; 
a.download = 'Sample.pdf'; 
a.style.display = 'none'; 
document.body.appendChild(a); 
a.click(); document.body.removeChild(a);
```

The href if any domain apart from stackoverflow, will open the document instead of downloading it.

Comment: Looked into browser support? or supply the code your using if your manipulating the attribute.

Comment: @Kenyanke:   PFB the snippet:                                                                                   
         var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = selectedStore.pdfLink;
            a.download = 'Sample.pdf';
            a.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);                                           The href if any domain apart from stackoverflow, will open the document instead of downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed similar issues with cross-domain PDF documents.

I was able to resolve the issue by adding a http header to the PDF document:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Sample.pdf"`

If your PDF document was stored for example in S3, it would be easy to add the header manually as well as programmatically (during initial upload of the document). If you don't have control over the PDF document HTTP headers you will need another solution.